# bugzilla | perl module installation nightmare: no cc, is gcc OK?

Tags: perl, gcc, ubuntu, installation, bugzilla

I am trying to install Bugzilla.  I don't recall it being so difficult.  We have a ubuntu server on the cloud, and at first I attempted to install through the rackspace UI.  This didn't work, so I ssh'ed in and actually downloaded the tarball to do it the old-fashioned way.

However, it appears there are three perl modules having install problems.  I have tried everything I know to get them to install, and am at a loss.  I've tried googling for some answers, but I am either not using the correct terminology or this is truly unique to my situation.

The three offending perl modules failing the checksetup.pl:

```
/usr/bin/perl install-module.pl DateTime
/usr/bin/perl install-module.pl DateTime::TimeZone
/usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Template
```

When I attempt to install any of them, they fail miserably, apparently because the cc compiler is not installed (see below).  When I checked for a cc package under APT, I could only find gcc.  Will that be sufficient, and will I need to alias gcc to cc in order for these installs to work?

```
/usr/bin/perl /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -typemap /usr/share/perl/5.10/ExtUtils/typemap  Stash.xs > Stash.xsc && mv Stash.xsc Stash.c
cc -c   -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DDEBIAN -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O2 -g   -DVERSION=\"2.22\" -DXS_VERSION=\"2.22\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib/perl/5.10/CORE"   Stash.c
/bin/sh: cc: not found
make[1]: *** [Stash.o] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/.cpan/build/Template-Toolkit-2.22-xzQg_q/xs'
make: *** [subdirs] Error 2
  ABW/Template-Toolkit-2.22.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
Skipping test because of notest pragma
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

Comment: "apt-get install bugzilla" may be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Install GCC and then Perl.To install the gcc package in the Debian/Ubuntu Linux distribution, enter the following command in a terminal:

```
> apt-get install gcc make linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't compile Perl with one compiler (`cc`) and then compile modules with another compiler or compiler build (`gcc`) unless you happen to know their compatible. I find it very hard to believe that Ubuntu provided a Perl built with a compiler they don't provide.

Then there's the issue that you're installing unmanaged modules into a distro-managed Perl. That's... less than ideal.

The simplest solution is probably:

```
apt-get install \
    libdatetime-perl \
    libdatetime-timezone-perl \
    libtemplate-perl
```

Another solution is to install a local build of Perl, perhaps using [`perlbrew`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?App%3a%3aperlbrew).

Personally, I never use the system Perl. It's there for the system's needs first (not mine), and that causes problems. In this case, since the distro does provide the packages you need, it should be fine to just install those packages.

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and installed the gcc package, and the installs completed. Whew.  It has been a long time...

Comment: As I recall, the `gcc` package installs `/usr/bin/cc` as a symlink to `gcc`.

Comment: On Debian/Ubuntu one is supposed to install the meta-package `build-essential` which pulls in not only the compiler, but also related necessary tools like make.

Comment: Keith Thompson, I could not find the gcc package - I did look. (I was not the one to build this ubuntu box.)  @daxim, thanks for the recommendation.